# How to collect the removed values from array_filter in php

Tags: php

I have a very big array that I need to filter it. I have the following to removed some values from my array:

```
$subscrip = array_values(array_filter(
  $subscrip,
  function ($rec) {
    $NoGroup = ['ea-g1', 'rex-ra'];
    if (in_array($rec['stage'], $NoGroup) && preg_match('/(pf|theme)$/', $rec['sgroup'])) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
));
```

It is working but I need to collect the values that array_filter removed as well.

In addition: The elements of $subscrip are arrays by themselves. So I can not use array_diff because array_diff can only compare strings or values that can be casted to (string).

Second addition:
I tried the following code:

```
$removed = [];
$subscrip = array_values(array_filter($subscrip, function ($rec) use (&$removed) {
  $NoGroup = ['ea-g1', 'rex-ra'];
  if (in_array($rec['stage'], $NoGroup) && preg_match('/(pf|theme)$/', $rec['sgroup'])) {
    $removed[] = $rec;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}));
print_r($remove);
```

The result of print_r($remove) is empty like the following:

```
Array
(
)
```

Third addition: Here an example of my original array:

```
   [1] => Array
        (
            [sgroup] => siteone
            [stage] => test1
            [s_host] => staging-21
            [product_type] => Basic
            [n_id] => 14286
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sgroup] => sitetwo
            [stage] => ea-g1
            [s_host] => staging-14
            [product_type] => Global
            [n_id] => 78951
        )
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: make a diff orginal - filtered = remaning. With array_diff()

Comment: `array_filter` does not store removed values. Use a simple `foreach` loop and gather items to different arrays.

Comment: The reason why the array was empty is that you used `print_r($remove)` and the array was called `$removed`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple way to achieve this:

```
$removed = [];
$subscrip = array_values(array_filter($subscrip, function ($rec) use (&$removed) {
  $NoGroup = ['ea-g1', 'rex-ra'];
  if (in_array($rec['stage'], $NoGroup) && preg_match('/(pf|theme)$/', $rec['sgroup'])) {
    $removed[] = $rec;
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}));
```

**[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/75ors)**

Comment: I used this technic and I printed the array by print_r() but the array is empty. I think because the elements of $subscrip are arrays by itself. Also array_diff can only compare strings or values that can be casted to (string). But the elements of $subscrip are arrays by themselves. Do you have any solution for this.

Comment: What do you mean the array is empty? It shouldn't be unless your filter function always returns true. Can you show your updated code (maybe edit it in in the question)?

Comment: I used your example and then I used print_r($removed); to print the array and the result was Array
(
)

Comment: I do not know what was the issue but now it is working.+1

Comment: Just in case you missed my comment of the question but they were printing a variable called `$remove` which should have been `$removed`.

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter` has no option for storing items that do not fit the condition. You can just iterate over your source array and put items to two different subarrays, for example:

```
$items = [
    'correct' => [],
    'incorrect' => [],
];
$NoGroup = ['ea-g1', 'rex-ra'];
foreach ($subscrip as $rec) {
    $key = in_array($rec['stage'], $NoGroup) && preg_match('/(pf|theme)$/', $rec['sgroup']) ? 'incorrect' : 'correct';
    $items[$key][] = $rec;
}
```